# Enviar notificación push firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, fcm

quiero enviar una notificación cuando se haga un cambio en la base datos. La quiero mandar a todos los dispositivos. Ya vi algunos ejemplos pero no entendi bien como hacerlo, logré poder leer la base de datos. Paso qué es lo que tengo.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
exports.newMessage = functions.firestore.document('/Usuarios/{user}/Parejas/{match}/Chat/Mensajes').onWrite((change,context)=>{
    //Aca quiero enviar la notificación
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea detras de enviar a todos tus usuarios es la siguiente.

Primero tenes que almacenar todos los tokens de los usuarios en tu base de datos, los vas a tener que almacenar o en el UID del usuario que se loguea o en un nodo aparte (es mejor en el UID para poder identificar el token de cada usuario), pero en un nodo aparte los podes replicar a la hora de tener que mandar a todos y solo consultar esos tokens.

Recorda que vos lo que queres hacer es enviar una notificacion cada vez que se escribe el nodo Mensajes, para eso tenes que atachar un after para saber lo que tenes que hacer despues que se escribe el documento

```
const user = context.params.user;
const match = context.params.match;

    if (!change.after.val()) {
            return console.log('El usuario ', user, 'quito el mensaje para', match);
          }
          console.log('Tenemos un nuevo mensaje de UID:', user , 'para:', match);
```

Luego para terminar, lo que tenes que hacer es conseguir el token de cada usuario para enviar el mensaje

const obtenerToken = admin.database()
          .ref(`/Usuarios/${usuario}/tokens`).once('value');

Recorda que ese token lo tenes que subir a la base de datos desde el cliente

Para obtenerlo podes hacer lo siguiente

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {    
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {    
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();    
        registerToken(token);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token) {

    }
}
```

Para finalizar , tenes que crear un payload para mandar el mensaje

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Tienes un nuevo mensaje!',
          body: `${user.nombre} te envio un mensaje.`,
          icon: user.fotoURL
        }
      };
```

Para entender mejor el concepto te dejo dos repos, uno de google oficial, y otro que hice yo comentado al español

Firebase functions ejemplos: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Mi ejemplo: https://github.com/gastsail/Google-Cloud-Functions/blob/master/TurnosFCM/functions/index.js